# INSERT INTO where some of the data is dependent on a select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, insert-into

I understand how to do an insert into when all the input data is known, and I know how to do an insert into when all the data is dependent on a select, but I can't find how to do the in between. Where I'm at now:

```
INSERT INTO takes (stu_id, "CS-001", 1, "Autumn", 2009, null)
VALUES (SELECT id AS stu_id
FROM student
WHERE dept_name = "Comp. Sci.")
```

Thus I know all the other input data except the student's id, however MySQL just gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO takes (stu_id, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) 
SELECT id, 'CS-001', 1, 'Autumn', 2009, null
FROM student 
WHERE dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.'
```

I don't know your destination column names - you have to replace them with the real ones in the query above.

Comment: That was my first try, and it doesn't work at all (even when it's id instead of stu_id). It's a massive syntax error with error code 1064

Comment: @user2171584: This will work with the correct column names of the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Insert queries can be structured like this:

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
(value1, value2 etc)
```

or like this:

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
select this, that, etc
from etc
```

You tried to combine the two.  That's one of the reasons you got an error.

juergen's answer is an example of the 2nd construct.  His this and that is a combination of fields and constant values.  That's perfectly ok.  If you are getting syntax errors, it's in your details.  His answer shows the right general idea.

It's often worthwhile to build your query step by step.  Start with this:

```
insert into takes
(stu_id)
select id
from student
where dept_name = 'Comp. Sci'
```

If that works, add one field inside the brackets and whatever is appropriate to the select clause of your query.  Keep going with these baby steps until you get it right.  It's an approach I often take.